# Converting float to character array in MikroC program for PIC Microcontroller

Tags: floating-point, embedded, converters, mikroc

I was trying to modify a program i got on the internet, which i found here:

[Interfacing Ultrasonic distance sensor ASCII output using PIC Microcontroller](http://electrosome.com/interfacing-ultrasonic-distance-sensor-ascii-pic-microcontroller/)

I need to do some calculations on the distance before i can output it to the LCD display.I successfully converted the string to float. Its code is here:

```
// LCD module connections
sbit LCD_RS at RB7_bit;
sbit LCD_EN at RB6_bit;
sbit LCD_D4 at RB5_bit;
sbit LCD_D5 at RB4_bit;
sbit LCD_D6 at RB3_bit;
sbit LCD_D7 at RB2_bit;
sbit LCD_RS_Direction at TRISB7_bit;
sbit LCD_EN_Direction at TRISB6_bit;
sbit LCD_D4_Direction at TRISB5_bit;
sbit LCD_D5_Direction at TRISB4_bit;
sbit LCD_D6_Direction at TRISB3_bit;
sbit LCD_D7_Direction at TRISB2_bit;
// End LCD module connections

void main()
{
    int i,temp;
    char dist[] = "000.0";
    float v,h,l=25,b=25;
    Lcd_Init(); // Initialize LCD
    UART1_Init(9600); //Initialize the UART module
    Lcd_Cmd(_LCD_CLEAR); // Clear display
    Lcd_Cmd(_LCD_CURSOR_OFF); // Cursor off
    Lcd_Out(1,1,"Distance= cm");
    do
    {
        if(UART1_Data_Ready()) //if data ready
        {
            if(UART1_Read() == 0x0D) //check for new line character
            {
                for(i=0;i<5;)
                {
                    if(UART1_Data_Ready()) // if data ready
                    {
                        dist[i] = UART1_Read();  // read data
                        i++;
                    }
                }
            }
         }
         h=(100*(dist[0]-48))+(10*(dist[1]-48))+(dist[2]-48)+(0.1*(dist[4]-48));
         v=l*b*h*0.001;
         //sprintf(dist,"%f",v);
         Lcd_Out(1,10,dist);
    }while(1);
}
```

Would sprintf() work if i added stdio? or would i have to write the logic from scratch?Or can i use some other library functions?

Answer (score 0):

Yes sprintf() should convert the floating point value into a string.

Some microcontroller libraries come with different versions of sprintf().  The minimal version, designed to conserve code space, may not support the `%f` format field.  So ensure you are linking with the library version that supports the `%f` format field.

Are you sure that your char array, `dist`, is long enough?  You don't want sprintf() to overflow the char array.  You can limit the number of decimal places output by sprintf() to one by changing the format specifier from `"%f"` to `"%.1f"`.  That will protect you on one end but then you still need to protect from overflow when `v` >= 1000.0.  Consider using sprintfn() instead of sprintf().